# AJAX post not getting any response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

So when I click on a button on my register page (register.php), the jQuery should make an AJAX post request to regit.php. In the jQuery I added a debug message (it indeed registers the button click) but nothing happens after it. No data is returned to the result div, nothing.

I have tried finding the mistake but just cant spot it.

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

$("form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked button");

    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var passwordconfirm = $('#password_confirm').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var turvakysimus = $('#turvakysimus').val();
    var turvavastus = $('#turvavastus').val();

    $.post("regit.php",
    {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        passwordconfirm: passwordconfirm,
        email: email,
        turvakysimus: turvakysimus,
        turvavastus: turvavastus
    },

    function(data)
    {
        if(data.tulemus == 'olemas') {
             $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Success!</strong></div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } else if (data.tulemus == 'loodud'){
            $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Error!</strong></div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } 
    }, "json");
});
});
```

The regit.php where the request is sent to:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['username'])){

include_once 'db_connect.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordconfirm = $_POST['passwordconfirm'];

$email = $_POST['email'];
$turvakysimus = $_POST['turvakysimus'];
$turvavastus = $_POST['turvavastus'];

$sql = "SELECT username FROM kasutajad WHERE username = :username";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$query->bindValue(':username', $username);
$query->execute();

$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($query->rowCount()){
    echo json_encode(array("tulemus"=>"olemas"));
} else {

  $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, turvakysimus, turvavastus) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :turvakysimus, :turvavastus)";
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

  $query->bindValue(':username', $username);
  $query->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);
  $query->bindValue(':email', $email);
  $query->bindValue(':turvakysimus', $turvakysimus);
  $query->bindValue(':turvavastus', $turvavastus);

  $result = $query->execute();

  if($result){
       echo json_encode(array("tulemus"=>"loodud"));
  }
}
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.. I just hope it isn't a stupid typo somewhere.

Comment: 1. look in the (network) console
2. add fail/error to the jQuery post. 
3. Add PHP error handling, use GET and load the URL into the location to see if there are errors there.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at **[jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)** and try to add `fail` function so it will be handled if there's any problem :

```
$.post("regit.php",
{
    username: username,
    password: password,
    passwordconfirm: passwordconfirm,
    email: email,
    turvakysimus: turvakysimus,
    turvavastus: turvavastus
}, function(result) {
    alert( "success" );
    console.log(result);
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok try to add `result` param and `console.log(result);`, see my updated code answer, and tell us what you receive in your browser developer console.

Comment: The problem is in the query not being executed.

Comment: So the problem is not in ajax request but in php code, you have to debug your code using `echo`s and see if the process will done successfully, example : you can add an echo in first of you `regit.php` page and check if you will receive the value of this echo in your result.

Comment: I added an else statement to if($result){ and it printed it out. Something wrong with the query I guess.

Comment: Why are you using this if and else ? are you tested the basic code in my answer ? (without conditions).

Comment: Thanks, it was a problem in the query (one of the field names didn't match).

Comment: Ok good job, you're welcome, if the answer help you vote it up, if the answer is what you looking for mark it as correct answer.